# Выбор способа оплаты в paymaster?

Tags: php, веб-программирование, платежи

Здравствуйте. Нужно сделать оплату на сайте с помощью paymaster, встал вопрос о выборе оплаты, читал что paymaster поддерживает множество способов оплаты, но как их использовать я так и не нашел. Собственно вопрос, как можно предоставить пользователю возможность оплачивать чем-то, помимо карты? Может есть какие-то варианты чтобы вести пользователя на страницу с определенным способом оплаты, или же на страницу с выбором способа оплаты?

И еще один маленький вопросик. Есть ли в paymaster возможность наложить комиссию поверх желаемой суммы? К примеру если комиссия 2.7%, и мне нужно получить от пользователя 1000 рублей, то чтобы он оплачивал сумму в 1027 рублей?

Comment: лучше добавить ссылку на систему Paymaster в вопрос и написать на чем вы собираетесь писать эту функциональность